# How to define Date Range for Parameters in Report Builder

Tags: dax, reportbuilder, powerbi-paginated-reports

I have a request to have a date range filter based on submission date in a paginated report, I am able to create the date range and it's working, however the report has only 3 years worth of data and the date range showed in filters displays all possible dates from 1800s, so users can select older dates although there's no data for those dates. I am trying to limit the date range filter to the relative dates in the dataset but I can't figure a way to do that.  My paginated report is connected to a PBI dataset so I am using dax.

This is my query

---

```
DEFINE

MPARAMETER s_start_dt = FORMAT(@s_start_dt, "MM/dd/yyyy")
MPARAMETER s_end_dt = FORMAT(@s_end_dt, "MM/dd/yyyy")


VAR __Table1 =

 SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
 Query1[Category],
 Query1[Aggregate Underwriting Comp],
 Query1[violation_id_link],
 FILTER(VALUES(Query1[sbmsn_dt]),Query1[sbmsn_dt]>= @s_start_dt && Query1[sbmsn_dt]<= @s_end_dt)

 )

EVALUATE __Table1
ORDER BY Query1[sbmsn_dt] desc
```

---

the parameters are defined as Date/Time with no available values nor default values

Below is a screenshot of how I see the date range right now, any help would be appreciated!
[image]

I also have tried the usual way where I add a calendar data source with relative dates (min and max based on my dataset), but this displays 2 boxes in the report for From and To Dates with dropdown to choose the date (like a dropdown text) which is not very intuitive [image]

Answer (score 0):

Since it's DAX, I'm wondering if you can use the Calendar table trick...

```
Calendar = CALENDAR(
   MINX('Query1',[sbmsn_dt]),
   MAXX('Query1',[sbmsn_dt])
)
```

and then use that as the source for your date filters (It will return all dates between your earliest and latest dates in Query1[sbmsn_dt].

Comment: When I do it the regular way (by adding parameters from calendar table with the relative dates) I get 2 boxes for "From Date" and "To Date" that have a dropdown selection of dates rather than an actual calendar to choose from (first option not very intuitive)